# gzip javascript files not with the server

Tags: javascript, gzip

The answer to gzipping javascript files is always some variant of "let the server do it", but what if I want to locate javascript files at URIs that are not behind my web server? How can I  store gzipped files and ensure browsers will correctly render the javascript? Do I need to add some header data at the beginning of the file itself for the major browsers to correctly use the file? And how can I accomplish that, since the file is binary? I tried encoding as base 64, but could not get that to work either. (My experiments were with the js URI behind my IIS 7 server.)

Comment: I think you may not like this comment but... locate javascript files at URIs that are behind webservers that automagically do gzip compression?   ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  You need to set the [`Content-Encoding`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.11) header.

Comment: ...well, may not be possible, that's what I'm trying to find out.